# Como transferir o itens entre ListBox com Double Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Gostaria de saber como posso transferir itens entre dois ListBox, quero que quando o usuário de dois clicks sobre um item o mesmo sejá transferido de um listbox para o outro.

Não encontrei nenhum evento no meu Asp-ListBox de doble click.

No link abaixo tem um exemplo do controle Telerik mas ele é pago, preciso de alguma solução como JavaScript

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listbox/examples/functionality/transfer/defaultcs.aspx

Consegui encontrar uma solução para o meu problema, não sei se é a melhor pratica mas funcionou da forma que eu precisava, O java script chama o evento do botão que faz o trabalho de trocar os itens sem causar problema na hora de gravar.

Código do Botão

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbDireita" ImageUrl="~/Imagens/Icones/SetaDireita.png"  runat="server" OnClick="imgbDireita_Click" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbEsquerda" ImageUrl="~/Imagens/Icones/SetaEsquerda.png" runat="server" OnClick="imgbEsquerda_Click" />
```

Evento dos Botões

```
protected void imgbDireita_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstCompartimentosAtivos.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            lstCompartimentosInativos.Items.Add(lstCompartimentosAtivos.Items[lstCompartimentosAtivos.SelectedIndex]);
            lstCompartimentosAtivos.Items.RemoveAt(lstCompartimentosAtivos.SelectedIndex);
            lstCompartimentosInativos.SelectedIndex = -1;
            lstCompartimentosAtivos.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }

 protected void imgbEsquerda_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstCompartimentosInativos.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            lstCompartimentosAtivos.Items.Add(lstCompartimentosInativos.Items[lstCompartimentosInativos.SelectedIndex]);
            lstCompartimentosInativos.Items.RemoveAt(lstCompartimentosInativos.SelectedIndex);
            lstCompartimentosInativos.SelectedIndex = -1;
            lstCompartimentosAtivos.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
```

Java Script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

function ativoParaInativo() {
    var imgb = document.getElementById('<%=imgbDireita.ClientID%>');
          imgb.click();
}

function inativoParaAtivo() {
      var imgb = document.getElementById('<%=imgbEsquerda.ClientID%>');
            imgb.click();
}

        $('#cphConteudo_tabImovel_tabCompartimentos_lstCompartimentosAtivos').dblclick(function () {
            ativoParaInativo();
        });

        $('#cphConteudo_tabImovel_tabCompartimentos_lstCompartimentosInativos').dblclick(function () {
            inativoParaAtivo();
        });

});
```

Comment: Olhe se aqui pode te ajudar.
https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Answer (score 2):

Experimenta dar uma olhadinha:

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/how-to-move-items-between-listbox-using.html

Comment: Eu fiz o teste e na parte de exibição funciona mas na hora de gravar quando eu percorro o listBox no code behind ele não pega as alterações. Coloquei o código acima.

Comment: Como tu tá usando o componente asp, no submit eu não sei te dizer. Mas eu resolveria, por exemplo, salvando por ajax. Vc pode pegar o teu #cphConteudo_tabImovel_tabCompartimentos_lstCompartimentosAtivos e fazer um each nos itens. Dessa forma vai ter os ids da tb ativa e pode enviar um array. (=

Comment: Pode me mostra um exemplo de código de como fazer isso?

Comment: Mais ou menos assim: var lAtivos = new Array();
$("#cphConteudo_tabImovel_tabCompartimentos_lstCompartimentosAtivos .classeDoListItemPorExemplo").each(function () { 
  lAtivos.push($(this).attr("id"));
});


$.post("pagina.aspx", { acao: "salvar", listaIDs: lAtivos }, function (retorno) {

});
Não testei esse código. (=

Comment: Consegui resolver de outra forma, vou colocar o código em cima. Obrigado pela ajuda.